# Can we prove that there only exists one $\tau$ for this equation?

Tags: probability-distributions, solution-verification, monotone-functions

Suppose that we have $0<\tau<\infty$.

In addition, we are informed that the following equation for possible $\tau$ holds (there exists at least one $\tau$ such that the following equation holds):
\begin{equation}
\frac{f_1(\tau)}{f_0(\tau)}=\left[\frac{\int_{0}^{\tau}f_1(x)dx\int_{\tau}^{\infty}f_1(x)dx}{\int_{0}^{\tau}f_0(x)dx\int_{\tau}^{\infty}f_0(x)dx}\right]^{\frac{1}{2}} \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad(1)
\end{equation}
where $f_1(x)$ and $f_0(x)$ are two unknown probability density functions, $x\in (0,\infty)$, and we have
$$L(x)=\frac{f_1(x)}{f_0(x)}$$
is monotonically increasing w.r.t. $x$

Then, can we prove that there **only exists one** $\tau\in (0,\infty)$ such that (1) holds.

---

My approach:

Generally, for the concerned problem, we can study the monotonicity of the following function：
\begin{equation}
h(\tau)=\left[\frac{f_1(\tau)}{f_0(\tau)} \right]^2-\frac{\int_{0}^{\tau}f_1(x)dx\int_{\tau}^{\infty}f_1(x)dx}{\int_{0}^{\tau}f_0(x)dx\int_{\tau}^{\infty}f_0(x)dx}
\end{equation}
If $h^{\prime}(\tau)$ is always larger or smaller than $0$, then we deduce that there only exists one $\tau$ (recall that we already know that there at least exists one $\tau$ such that (1) holds).

However, from the $h^{\prime}(\tau)$, I can not judge the relationship between $h^{\prime}(\tau)$ and $0$.

---

Any helpful suggestions and answers will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a solution, but here is a counterexample to the monotonicity of $h$

Using  $f_1(x) = e^{-x}$ and $f_0(x) = 2e^{-2x}$, we have $f_1(x)/f_0(x) = e^{x}/2$, which is monotonically increasing. Next,
$$
\begin{align}
h(\tau)&=\left[\frac{f_1(\tau)}{f_0(\tau)} \right]^2-\frac{\int_{0}^{\tau}f_1(x)dx\int_{\tau}^{\infty}f_1(x)dx}{\int_{0}^{\tau}f_0(x)dx\int_{\tau}^{\infty}f_0(x)dx}\\
&=\frac{e^{-2\tau}}{4e^{-4\tau}} - \frac{(1-e^{-\tau})e^{-\tau}}{(1-e^{-2\tau})e^{-2\tau}}\\
&=\frac{e^{2\tau}}{4}-\frac{e^{2\tau}}{1+e^{\tau}}
\end{align}
$$
and so there is a solution to $h(\tau)=0$, namely $\tau=\ln(3)$. However, $h$ is not monotone, as
$$h'(\tau) =\frac{1}{2}e^{2\tau}-\frac{(1+e^{\tau})2e^{2\tau}-e^{\tau}(e^{2\tau})}{(1+e^{\tau})^2}$$
So $h'(0) = -\frac{1}{4} < 0$ whereas $h'(\ln(2))=\frac{2}{9}>0$

Comment: Thanks for your time！
It helps me a lot!